# How do I set Airflow's S3KeySensor to use regex key?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm new to Airflow and I'm using version 1.10.15 to create a dag that will scan s3 key in the bucket that already has data files in the following format using S3KeySensor:

```
daily_load_20220101.tgz
daily_load_20220102.tgz
```

I'm trying to sense for any new files that starts with daily_load_*. I'm not sure how to set the S3KeySensor to scan for files as such.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `apache-airflow-providers-amazon>=3.3.0`:

```
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.sensors.s3 import S3KeySensor
S3KeySensor(
    task_id='s3_key_sensor',
    bucket_key='s3://test_bucket/daily_load_*',
    wildcard_match=True
)
```

For `apache-airflow-providers-amazon<3.3.0`:

You should use `S3PrefixSensor` however this sensor is not so easy to understand. This was one of the reason it was deprecated in newer version (you can see https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/22737 )
In general this should work:

```
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.sensors.s3 import S3PrefixSensor
S3PrefixSensor(
    task_id='s3_key_sensor',
    bucket_name='test_bucket',
    prefix=['daily_load_']
)
```